# Selenium throws MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException while using negative value in the moveByOffset method of Actions class

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scroll inside an element using the moveByOffset method of Actions class:

**HTML code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<style>
#container
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
#content
{
    margin:4px, 4px; 
    padding:4px; 
    width: 500px; 
    height:500px; 
    text-align:justify; 
    background-color: #ccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">Click the button to slide right!</div>
</div>

<script>
const button = document.getElementById('slide');
button.onclick = function ()
{
document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 20;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Selenium code:**

```
Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
// Scroll down
ac.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='container']"))).moveByOffset(0, 100).release().build().perform();
// Scroll up
ac.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='container']"))).moveByOffset(0, -100).release().build().perform();
// Scroll right
ac.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='container']"))).moveByOffset(100, 0).release().build().perform();
// Scroll left
ac.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='container']"))).moveByOffset(-100, 0).release().build().perform();
```

It is throwing MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException whenever we give negative value in the moveByOffset method.

Note: I know I can use javascript, but I want to do it using Actions class.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

**Actions.clickAndHold(element)**

> Clicks (without releasing) in the middle of the given element. This is
> equivalent to: Actions.moveToElement(onElement).clickAndHold()

**Actions.moveToElement()**

> Moves the mouse to the middle of the element. The element is scrolled
> into view and its location is calculated using getBoundingClientRect.

So one your clickandhold(element) the mouse pointer is at coordinate 50:50 (middle of container, and not edge)  , so the movetoelement bound value will be -50 to +50 , not 0 to 100.

so if you want to move to left or right , or top or bottom, you have to give -50 and +50 .  if you give -100 will be equal to  50+ -100 which will be less than 0 which is out of bound.

-100 +50 (where 50 is the current location)

**Fix 1:** ( use current position as (50,50) and move +50 and -50 pixel only)

```
Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
// Scroll down
ac.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='container']"))).moveByOffset(-50, -50).release().build().perform();
// Scroll up
ac.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='container']"))).moveByOffset(-50, 50).release().build().perform();
// Scroll right
ac.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='container']"))).moveByOffset(50, -50).release().build().perform();
// Scroll left
ac.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='container']"))).moveByOffset(-50, -50).release().build().perform();
```

**Fix 2:** (Explicitly move element to containers (0,0) coordinate)

```
   Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
    // Scroll down ( already down )
    ac. moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='container']")), 0, 0).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, 0).release().build().perform();
    // Scroll up
        ac. moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='container']")), 0, 0).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, 100).release().build().perform();    

// Scroll right
        ac. moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='container']")), 0, 0).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(100, 0).release().build().perform();

    // Scroll left (Already at left)
        ac. moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='container']")), 0, 0).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, 0).release().build().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for clear and concise explanation.